# What RF antenna connector is this?

Tags: identification, connector, radio

What type of RF connector is this? I think it might be SMA, but I might be wrong.

After fiddling with the autofocus forever:
[image: A real image.]

And here are the dimensions:

- ~7-8mm diameter
- center pin ~1mm and from the center to the outside shell of the
  connector is ~3 to ~5mm (I'd guess 3-4)
- ~2.5mm from the center pin to the inner grooves

I got it from a surplus electronics store for free and I was wondering what adapter it would take to convert it to a wifi antenna. I can find no specs of it online.

The antenna itself is in a [AN/ALQ-196](http://fas.org/man/dod-101/sys/ac/equip/an-alq-196.htm) antenna set.

Answer (score 1):

The photo that you just posted now is of a standard SMA connector.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it might be a 3.5mm connector, which is mechanically compatible with SMA but has an air dielectric and a wider bandwidth (26.5 GHz). It could also be SMA, though. It's a bit hard to tell from the picture. What is the frequency range of the antenna that it is supposed to be connected to?